# Azure Stream Analytics : remove duplicates while aggregating

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics

I'm working on a system of temperature and pressure sensors, where my data is flowing through a Stream analytics job. Now there maybe duplicate messages sent in because of acknowledgements not being received and various other reasons. So my data could be of the format:-

```
DeviceID    TimeStamp    MeasurementName     Value

1           1            temperature         50
1           1            temperature         50
1           2            temperature         60
```

Note that the 2nd record is a duplicate of the 1st one as DeviceId and Timestamp and MeasurementName are same. 
I wish to take an average over 5 min tumbling window for this data in the stream analytics job. So I have this query

```
SELECT
    AVG(Value)
FROM
    SensorData
GROUP BY
    DeviceId,
    MeasurementName,
    TumblingWindow(minute, 5)
```

This query is expected to give me average measurement of temperature and pressure values for each device in 5 min.
In doing this average I need to eliminate duplicates. The actual average is (50+60)/2 = 55.
But the average given my this query will be (50+50+60)/3 = 53.33

How do I tweak this query for the right output?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Query Language Elements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/query-language-elements-azure-stream-analytics) in ASA,it seems that distinct is not supported by ASA directly. However, you could find it could be used with `COUNT` from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/count-azure-stream-analytics).

So,may be you could refer to my below sql to get avg of Value without duplicate data.

```
with temp as
(
select count(distinct DeviceID) AS device,
count(distinct TimeStamp) AS time,
count(distinct MeasurementName) AS name,
Value as v
from jsoninput
group by Value,TumblingWindow(minute, 5)
)
select avg(v) from temp
group by TumblingWindow(minute, 5)
```

***Output with your sample data:***

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Very helpful.

Comment: @user3740951 Glad to help you.